# Inferring the convex combination parameter of two Poissons

Tags: poisson-distribution, inference

Suppose I am interested in estimating an unknown quantity $p\in[0,1]$. I am limited to drawing three random samples, $X\sim\mathrm{Pois}(\alpha)$, $Y\sim\mathrm{Pois}(\beta)$, and $Z\sim\mathrm{Pois}(\gamma)$ where $\gamma=p\alpha+(1-p)\beta$. 
The quantities $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are unknown, but I am happy putting a prior on them.

The most obvious estimator, I think, is a frequentist estimator derived by inverting the formula for $\gamma$ and solving for $p$:
$$
\hat{p}=\frac{Z-Y}{X-Y}
$$
This is undefined when $X=Y$, but $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are sufficiently different that this would only happen with a very small probability.

My questions are: How would I go about putting a confidence interval on my estimator above? What other choices of estimator would make sense? Are there others that are obviously better? What would be a good Bayesian approach? Am I basically stuck doing numerics to work out confidence/credible regions?

Sorry if this is vague, I am relatively new to statistical inference.

Comment: Supposing you draw $\hat{X},\hat{Y},\hat{Z}$ respectively, you could form an MLE problem via maximizing $P_{\alpha}(\hat{X})P_{\beta}(\hat{Y})P_{\gamma}(\hat{Z})$ subject to $\gamma=p\alpha+(1-p)\beta$.

Answer (score 1):

Going off on my comment, we have that $P_{\lambda}(x)=e^{-\lambda}\lambda^x/x!$, so that setting up the log-likelihood gives:

$$L=-\alpha-\beta-\gamma+\hat{X}\ln(\alpha)+\hat{Y}\ln(\beta)+\hat{Z}\ln(\gamma)-\ln(\hat{X}!\hat{Y}!\hat{Z}!),$$

subject to the constraint $\gamma-p\alpha-(1-p)\beta=0$. The lagrange multiplier equation gives:

\begin{align*}
-1+\frac{\hat{X}}{\alpha}&=-\lambda p\\
-1+\frac{\hat{Y}}{\beta}&=-\lambda (1-p)\\
-1+\frac{\hat{Z}}{\gamma}&=\lambda 
\end{align*}

We get that $\lambda=-1+\frac{\hat{Z}}{p\alpha+(1-p)\beta}$. This is not fun to solve, so perhaps you should settle on a numerical approximation using a minimization algorithm of your choice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is MLE a good way to go even when 2 out of three of the parameters are nuisance parameters?

Comment: @IanHincks: I'm not sure its accurate to call $\alpha,\beta$ nuisance parameters as they directly influence $\gamma$. I would think that if you treat them as nuisance parameters, then your estimate for $\gamma$ would simply be $Z$?

Comment: But the goal is to estimate $p$...

Comment: @Ian Hinks: just to clarify, gamma is known?

Comment: $\gamma$ is known to obey the stated relationship. $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $p$ are unknown.